# can't visit the websocket in browser from rosbridge

Tags: rosbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use rosbridge to roslaunch a websocket in ros,and the port is 9090.And I input ip:port in browser,but i find this http error 400 and the text--- "Can "Upgrade" only to "WebSocket".".

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223798/can%27t-visit-the-websocket-in-browser-from-rosbridge/) by [shuwangyi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25529/shuwangyi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-01-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on 2016-11-17**:
If you're using default ports for video_web_server, then 9090 is for socket streams (can't connect via browser) and 8080 is http for the page you're looking for (http://localhost:8080)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think you can just connect your browser to a websocket server, you need a program that talks the websocket protocol. The server doesn't serve a http page, but wants to upgrade the connection to ws. A Javascript program running in a browser could be used to connect using websocket, see http://wiki.ros.org/roslibjs/Tutorials/BasicRosFunctionality

**Edit:**
There is no ROS webbrowser, you can use a standard webbrowser. The Websocket Server is running under ROS. From the roslibjs Tutorial page: Running the Example starts with starting the Server and publishing messages, but the last 5 lines say: You can open the html file in a local webbrowser (open file) on the same machine, or you could setup a webserver (for html files) and serve this html-file to a webbrowser on a remote machine.

I haven't used rosbride yet, just a C++ websocket library in a system that had nothing to do with ROS.

---

Originally posted by [fsteinhardt](https://answers.ros.org/users/4889/fsteinhardt/) with karma: 306 on 2016-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shuwangyi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25529/shuwangyi/) on 2016-01-11**:
Thanks a lot .But I also don't know if I write a HTML page with javascript program in ros,how can i connect it in non-ros browser?And in roslibjs Tutorials "1.4 Running the Example", i don't have seen the HTML page is used in following action.